# Async function returns Promise <Pending> instead of a value

Tags: node.js, promise

Trying to log rs which should be the value of the function create order but it returns promise pending

```js
let createOrder = async function () {
  let response = await client.execute(request);

  return response
};

let rs = createOrder().then((result) => console.log(result))

console.log("rsssss",rs)
```

Comment: Isn't it the whole point of async functions?

Comment: sure but the point here is  .then method isn't giving me a result , so maybe a suggestion what i did wrong . thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) always returns a promise

Comment: thanks but still not the result

Comment: You always have to wait for the promise to resolve. Either with `await` or `.then`

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the correct code pattern to handle async/Promises.
When you're chaining methods, the promise is resolved inside the callback, not outside.

The return of `.then()` method is a promise object.

The correct code is this:

```js
let createOrder = async function () { 
  let response = await client.execute(request);
  return response 
};

createOrder().then((result)=> {
  //the promise is resolved here
  console.log(result)
}).catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

Comment: i appreciate it but this actually doesnt show me anything in the console :/

Comment: I edited the code example to catch any errors that maybe is happening. Please show us the code behing `client.execute(request)`, I'm sure that this function is not resolving the promise or it is throwing a exception not handled somewhere.

Comment: It is actually a method from the paypal  library, a checkout npm

Comment: Well, the code I've posted is correct, certainly there's an error somewhere in other lines of your code, like promises not resolving, etc. Have you already tried to run my edited code that will print any error?  By the way, we can't guide you more if you not show us more code.

Comment: i am actually working with aws , and the crazy part is that when i run the code locally it works , and when i tried it on lambda function it didnt, thats why i made some changes and then decided to ask help from you guys . The rest of the code is not logic is just creation of an order that i am sure its not wrong . i appreciate a lot your help man